# Manage issues from Bitbucket/Github with desktop application

Tags: github, version-control, bitbucket, issue-tracking

I really love using Bitbucket or Github however I am often offline and unable to access the their issue pages for my projects. Recently Github release a Mac desktop application which allows to manage the repo, however I can't find any desktop application for Mac/Windows/Linux which will allow me to manage either Github or Bitbucket issues and then push them to the actual server.

Is there anything like that available? Or any other recommendation?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't find one for off-line management, unless you *buy* a [self-hosted GitHub ("GitHub Enterprise"](https://github.com/blog/978-introducing-github-enterprise)) that you would synchronize with your remote GitHub repos.

The other solution is to manage your issues in a separate local bug tracking, and then [use GitHub v3 API for Issues](http://developer.github.com/v3/issues/) in order to read/write the issues from the remote GitHub repo.
With [PitHub](https://github.com/plu/Pithub), you even have an [API wrapper in Perl for Issues](https://metacpan.org/module/Pithub%3a%3aIssues).

Comment: Any sugestions for a good offline issue management?

Answer (score 3):

I realize this is an old question, but you could use: http://bughubapp.com/

Comment: cool. is there anything for bitbucket?

Comment: Unfortunatelly I haven't found anything similar for Bitbucket.